# React Hot Module Reloader preventing mocha tests from running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React project which is running the `react-transform-hmr` hot module reloader, and all was running fine until I implemented mocha tests. 
When I run the tests I get the following error:

> throw new Error('locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object
>   with Hot Module ' + 'replacement API enabled. You should disable
>   react-transform-hmr in ' + 'production by using `env` section in Babel
>   configuration. See the ' + 'example in README:
>   https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr');

I have googled this, and found some information mentioning moving the hot module reloading setup out of the `.babelrc` file and into the Webpack config, which I did, and the tests ran fine, but then the Hot Module Reloading wasn't working.

After playing around, and not getting both to work together, I have reverted and thought I would ask for some help as I am truly stuck. Any ideas what I can do?

My babel config is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        ["transform-react-display-name"],
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
            "imports": ["react"],
            "locals": ["module"]
          }, {
            "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
            "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
          }]
        }]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        ["transform-react-display-name"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And my webpack config is as follows:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    }
    ]
  }
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working with the following in the package.json:

`"test": "export NODE_ENV=testing|| set NODE_ENV=testing&& mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./tests/test-helper.js \"./tests/**/*@(.js|.jsx)\"",`

This was taken from [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr/issues/72).

Comment: You can put all of those arguments (`--compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./tests/test-helper.js \"./tests/**/*@(.js|.jsx)\""`) into the file `test/mocha.opts`.